# C# Interpolation Graphic with Cokriging Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a matrix of numbers, like this:

26.9    21.3    18.2    17.0    24.6    26.9
25.5    20.6    18.4    26.8    19.6    24.7
27.1    27.6    27.6    22.8    28.3    29.3
28.7    26.2    28.6    29.4    29.9    29.1
34.8    32.7    20.6    23.3    23.9    27.6
25.7    32.1    24.8    27.5    30.8    28.3

With this matrix values and using the **cokriging algorithm** I need to generate a interpolation graphic like this:

[image]

Any library in C #?

Comment: ["Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), maybe try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Quantic What is wrong in the question? Why do you rate negatively? Because you think that I must publish in another site? I don't thinks it's enough to rate negatively.